# How HMAC works for ASP.Net web api

Tags: c#, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api

just was reading a article on web API with HMAC authentication from this url http://www.piotrwalat.net/hmac-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api/

**HMAC** is at all authentication type or is it only hashing technology ?
if it is authentication type then tell me reason briefly why it should be consider as authentication type ?

if possible some one briefly discuss what is **HMAC authentication** and How this type of authentication works for web api ?

what i understood from their article that server & client will share a common `secret key` and when client will request web api service then they will send hash of secret key along with request and web service will compare the hash `secret key` at its end and if match then it allow to call action ?

if i understood correctly then i have some question. suppose if am sending hash of a secret key to web api then how web api know what key client have ? because if web api has to generate hash of secret key what client used for comparing at service end then web api has to know which client is sending data. suppose web api provide different secret key to their client. so when client will generate hash of that key and send it to web api then how web api validate that hash at its end ?

**there is change of Replay attack for HMAC authentication for web api**

the article raise some points which is not clear to me to prevent the chance of Replay attack for HMAC authentication for web api.

the points are

Imagine a malicious third party intercepts a valid (properly authenticated) HTTP request coming from a legitimate client 
(eg. using a sniffer). Such a message can be stored and resent to our server at any time enabling attacker to repeat operations 
performed previously by authenticated users. Please note that new messages still cannot be created as the attacker does not 
know the secret nor has a way of retrieving it from intercepted data.

1) requests with different Date header values will have different signatures, thus attacker will not be able to modify the timestamp

we will generate hash based on secret key then how date comes to scene ? this points is not clear to me.

2) we introduce a requirement that no http request can be older than X [eg. 5] minutes - if for any reason the message is delayed for more than that it will have to be resent with a refreshed timestamp.

point two is not clear. what this area try to mean delayed for more than that it will have to be resent with a refreshed **timestamp**. when client will send first request and then client may send second request after 10/15 minute later.

please help me to understand how to protect web api when using HMAC hasing against Replay attack. thanks

Comment: From the article: _"the secret key (eg. password hash) is only shared between client and server once (eg. during user registration)"_. HMAC doesn't has the _shared secret_, it hashes the _message_.

Answer (score 2):

Your hash algorithm object is constructed using a secret key. You can then use the algorithm to create a hash from string data which can include a date time string or json or xml or whatever. The shared secret key must be converted to a byte array first. Here is an example.

```
public string Hash(string data)
{
    var dataAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    using (var hasher = new HMACSHA256(dataAsBytes))
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(dataAsBytes));
    }
}
```

Now imagine you are sending data from a c# client which includes the date that you're sending the data and perhaps a guid. You serialize the data into a string, and create a hash from that data. If there is an attempt to replay the data, the datetime will be quite different. You could set up a tolerance for date time differences on the server and reject messages that are older than some time period (e.g. 5 minutes) so a replay attempt would require the date to change, but changing this date would change the hash. Only the original sender can regenerate the hash for a new datetime.

Comment: first tell me HMAC is algo to create hash from a specific data or is it any kind of authentication. if u search google by hmac auth then u must see people call it HMAC auth.........is it right ?

Comment: suppose i am sending hash created from secret key and send it to web api service. so attacker capture the request and extract the hash and send a request with hash to web api just to pretend legitimate client before web api. so how data comes here into scene ?

Comment: The data is what you create a hash from. When the server receives the data and the hash, it uses the data and the shared key to recreated the hash and compare them. If the data changes or is tampered with, the hash becomes invalid.

Comment: Actually, the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code describes it very well. I've just given the code to make it so.

Comment: i like to know what are the code we need to write at service level as a result reply attack will not be possible ?

Comment: what are the difference between  HMAC-SHA1 and HMAC-MD5 ? which one is best and secure?

Comment: On the server, use the same method. the aByteArray is the private key shared between the server and client. The data is the data being passed from server to client. The client should send the hash separately to the data. so if it was in json it would be something like "{'data': 'a string containing the data and perhaps the date, or a bunch of strings in json format' }" and the hash would be the string created by this function. The server would then take the json string and pass it to the same function and compare the result to the hash passed over by the client.

Comment: HMAC-SHA1 and HMAC-MD5 are just different algorithms. HMACSHA256 is better as it has stronger encryption, but may be a bit slower. In the grand scheme of things I'd go for security over speed.

Answer (score 2):

The reply attack is prevented using like a part of your data string sent, a time stamp. So your client makes something like this:

```
string TimeStamp=DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
string HashedSignature= Hash(BillId.ToString()+UserId.ToString()+ TimeStamp + SecretCode);
RestClient.Post(BillId, UserId, TimeStamp, HashedSignature);
```

Then your server, before try to recompose the HashedSignature, check the TimeStamp and if it is older than a maximum value (5 seconds for example), and reject it. If it is within a valid time range, try to reconstruct with the received values and its knowledge of the SecretCode or Key (which was not sent) its own ServerHashedSignature. If the Received signature is equal to the server built signature, then you can infer the message is valid.